# translating RegEx syntax working in php and python to JS

Tags: javascript, php, python, regex

I have this RegEx syntax: "(?<=[a-z])-(?=[a-z])"

It captures a dash between 2 lowercase letters. In example below the second dash is captured:

Krynica-Zdrój, ul. Uzdro-jowa

Unfortunately I can't use <= in JS.
My ultimate goal is to remove the hyphen with RegEx replace.

Comment: I want to use replace to get rid of this hyphen.

Comment: About /\b-\b/g, it returns both hyphens. About the second pattern, I have no idea how to get it to work, without changes it doesn't detect anything.

Comment: Yes, I provided a solution below. Let me delete my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you need to remove the hyphen in between lowercase letters.

Use

```js
var s = "Krynica-Zdrój, ul. Uzdro-jowa";
var res = s.replace(/([a-z])-(?=[a-z])/g, "$1");
console.log(res);
```

Note the first lookbehind is turned into a simple capturing group and the second lookahead is OK to use since - potentially, if there are chunks of hyphenated single lowercase letters - it will be able to deal with overlapping matches.

*Details*:

- `([a-z])` - Group 1 capturing a lowercase ASCII letter
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?=[a-z])` - that is followed with a lowercase ASCII letter that is not added to the result
  -`/g` - a global modifier, search for all occurrences of the pattern
- `"$1"` - the replacement pattern containing just the backreference to the value stored in Group 1 buffer.

**VBA sample code**:

```
Sub RemoveExtraHyphens()
Dim s As String
Dim reg As New regexp

reg.pattern = "([a-z])-(?=[a-z])"
reg.Global = True

s = "Krynica-Zdroj, ul. Uzdro-jowa"
Debug.Print reg.Replace(s, "$1")
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried /([a-z])-(?=[a-z])/g and it returns "o-" in my example.

Comment: Where is *your* example? Please share. If you use *mine*, you will see it works well.

Comment: My example is Krynica-Zdrój, ul. Uzdro-jowa, I have checked /([a-z])-(?=[a-z])/g on https://regex101.com/#javascript, I also maybe don't understand something, so I'll explain that I need the pattern to be used in VBA which uses JS RegEx syntax.

Comment: Thank You, now everything is clear to me and works perfectly, just replaced Dim reg As New regexp with Dim reg As Object Set reg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp"), because I was getting error, probably had no reference to regexp.